# Trying to run a calculation that keeps on returning incorrect answer

Tags: vb.net, math, oledb

Trying to make a calculation for student grades in an MCQ. 30 q's, 4 marks for correct and -1 for incorrect.

The code below works when I do not put in the /120 part. For a record with 16 correct answers and 7 wrong answers, it returns a value of 57, which is what I want it to. But when I try to divide it by 120 to get a percentage value, it returns 63.94, can anybody explain how or why this happens?

I can upload more code if needs be.

Without "/ 120"

```
(Math.Round(((CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Correct")) * 4) - (CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Wrong")))), 2))
```

With "/ 120"

```
(Math.Round(((CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Correct")) * 4) - (CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Wrong"))) / 120), 2))
```

Comment: In situations like this, the thing to do is to NOT try to do the whole calculation in one line of code.  Break the whole thing up into its steps and perform each one on a separate line.  You can then step through the code line by line and determine exactly where it behaves differently to what you expect.  Hopefully you then work out the issue for yourself but, if you can't, at least you can provide us with ALL the relevant information.  This code deconstruction, testing and debugging is an inherent part of programming.  It's not just writing code.

Answer (score 0):

**multiplication/division before addition/substraction**

What you got, if we put in the actual values is: `16 * 4 - 7 / 120`

What you actually want is: `(16 * 4 - 7) / 120`

Answer (score 0):

```
(Math.Round(((CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Correct")) * 4) - (CDbl(objAssessment1.Item("Wrong"))) / 120), 2))
(Math.Round(((CDbl(16) * 4) - (CDbl(7)) / 120), 2))
(Math.Round(((16 * 4) - (7) / 120), 2))
(Math.Round(((16 * 4) - (7) / 120), 2))
(Math.Round(((64) - (7) / 120), 2))
```

The 64 and the 7 in parenthesis just evaluate to themselves.

```
(Math.Round((64 - 7 / 120), 2))
```

Now remember order of precedence from algebra - multiplication and division first.

```
(Math.Round((64 - 0.0583333333333333), 2))
```

Now the subtraction.

```
(Math.Round(63.94166666666667, 2))
```

Now the Math.Round

```
(63.94)
```

Removing the extra set of parenthesis 63.94 evaluates to itself

```
63.94
```

The whole problem was too many parenthesis and you missed on set to perform the subtraction before the division.
 jmcilhinney's suggestion in comments would be the best way to straighten this out. This really wasn't a programming problem but an arithmetic problem. :-)